# Google charts, is it possible to have 2 different vertical axis values?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, combo-chart, angular-google-chart

For better understanding of this question, let me show a working example in TradingView webpage, on which the following chart shows the combination of Momentum (area chart) + ADX (line chart):

[image: TradingView Example]

As you can see, there are 2 vertical values, at left side is the ADX which the scale goes usually from 0 to 60(+-), but the right side, it can grow much more.

On my attempt to achieve the same here, the momentum (area chart) has a huge range, and the adx (lineal chart) goes from 0 to 60, so when it tries to fit both values under the same scale, my blue line looks like it's almost zero, in comparison with the area chart values. (Mouse-over the blue line showing that is currently 43)

[image: My Attempt]

So I think you get the point, **would it be possible to have 2 scales/vAxis for each series of values?**

I checked documentation already but nothing here seems to refer to what I mention:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

And just in case you need the options provided to the chart, nothing advanced, just the basic examples:

```
options:{
    seriesType: 'area',
    series: {
      0: { type: 'line', color: 'blue' }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution over this post in the documentation, it is conceptually known as `DUAL-Y Charts`

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#dual-y-charts

Answer (score 0):

use option --> `targetAxisIndex` -- in the series option...

zero is the default v-axis

```
targetAxisIndex: 0
```

to create a second v-axis, assign one of the series to index 1

```
series: {
  1: {
      targetAxisIndex: 1
  }
}
```